# Projectiveness and Dedekind domains

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, dedekind-domain

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity and $M$ an $A$-module. Show that $M$ is flat if and only if $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is a flat $A_\mathfrak{m}$-module for all maximal $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq A$.  If, in addition, $A$ is a Dedekind domain, 
>   show that a finitely generated torsion-free $A$-module is projective.  Furthermore, show that any finitely generated $A$-module $M$ is the direct sum of a projective $A$-module and a sum of cyclic torsion modules.

How is this problem done?  What is the relationship between the three parts?

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what precisely you are looking for in an answer?

Comment: @AmiteshDatta I was looking for something ot at least get me started with writing the proof, which Alex Youcis has so kindly done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part follows from the usual argument with $\text{Tor}$. It's clear that if $M$ is flat, then so is $M_{\mathfrak{m}}$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$. Conversely, if $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is flat for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$, then for any $A$-module $N$

$$\text{Tor}_1^R(M,N)_\mathfrak{m}=\text{Tor}_1^{R_\mathfrak{m}}(M_\mathfrak{m},N_\mathfrak{m})=0$$

so, since being zero is a local property, $\text{Tor}_1^R(M,N)=0$. Since this was true for all $N$, $M$ is flat.

If $M$ is finitely generated and torsion free, then $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is a finitely generated torsion free $A_\mathfrak{m}$-module. Since $A$ is a Dedekind domain, this implies that $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is a DVR, and so $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is free (and in particular flat) by the structure theorem.

I'd like to hear your ideas for the last part, before I chip in.

Comment: Thank you.  This should get me started writing the proof.  I'll try to get to the next part myself.

Comment: Alright so $M=A^k\oplus I$ where $I$ is an ideal of $A$ and $M_\mathfrak{m}=A_\mathfrak{m}^k\oplus I_\mathfrak{m}$. So $M_\mathfrak{m}$ is projective. So $M$ is projective.

Comment: So for the last part, can we use that $M^\prime=A\oplus B$ where $A$ is torsion-free and $B$ is torsion, and have that $A$ is projective from the previous part?  I can't really tell where the cyclic comes in.

Comment: "Being zero is a local property". This sentence always sounds funny in my head, don't ask why.